# Formatting data into 3 columns

Tags: gwt

I'm using a service call to go get data out of a database, and then build a string that formats the data. Right now I'm returning 415 records, and I need to take these records and put them into 3 seperate columns on the page. I've looked into things like FlexTable and HTMLTable, but it seems like you have to specify what goes into each column, different widgets. Whereas in my case, the data should be treated as one widget, just separated into 3 columns. Thanks.

The data should be displayed like this:

```
Program name          Program name                Program name
Contact name          Contact name                Contact name
Email                 Email                       Email
Phone                 Phone                       Phone
Region                Region                      Region

Program name          Program name                Program name
Contact name          Contact name                Contact name
Email                 Email                       Email
Phone                 Phone                       Phone
Region                Region                      Region

Program name          Program name                Program name
Contact name          Contact name                Contact name
Email                 Email                       Email
Phone                 Phone                       Phone
Region                Region                      Region

Program name          Program name                Program name
Contact name          Contact name                Contact name
Email                 Email                       Email
Phone                 Phone                       Phone
Region                Region                      Region
```

Etc

Comment: Why have the data should be treated as one widget? What's the reason or advantage you think you can take?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [CellTable](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) or [DataGrid](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) widget when you need to display multiple rows of data with column headers. These widgets are specifically designed for this purpose.

UPDATE:

The example you posted can be implemented using a simple [custom widget](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html) that includes 5 `Label` widgets inside a FlowPanel. Then you can add as many of them as you need using standard CSS for displaying them the way you want (`float:left` if you want your design to be responsive, for example, or put them inside a FlexTable).

Comment: I don't necessarily need column headers, but in this case, I think that each block of data would represent one cell or row of data. I've updated my original post with an example of what the data should look like.

Comment: You don't need to add column headers in DataGrid.